# Find range by value Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need a function or something to return me a range in which specified value were found.

I am thinking about looping through specified range checking if the value in each cell equals the value I specified and building a range. Is there more elegant method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function I built. It returns a union range where the needed value were found:

```
Private Function FindRange(what As String, lookin As Range) As Range

    Dim cell As Range

    On Error GoTo errhandler

    For Each cell In lookin.Cells
        If UCase(cell.Value) = UCase(what) Then

            If findrange Is Nothing Then
                Set findrange = cell
            Else
                Set findrange = Application.Union(findrange, cell)
            End If

        End If
    Next cell

    Exit Function

errhandler:
    findrange = CVErr(xlErrNA)

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

try the below code. You can get the results in cells itself by using the formula.

```
=findvalueandrange(searchstring,selectyourrange)

Public Function findvalueandrange(findingtext As String, r As Range) As String
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In r.Cells
        If LCase(cell.Value) = LCase(findingtext) Then
            If findvalueandrange = "" Then
                findvalueandrange = cell.Address & ":" & cell.Value
            Else
                findvalueandrange = findvalueandrange & "|" & cell.Address & ":" & cell.Value
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

Hope you satisfied?